# NodeJs PowerShell Script in a promise

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

I have been trying to execute a PowerShell script using setImmediate as below:

There are two buttons on the web page; one button (CallScript) to send a post request at /ExecutePS and other button (GetData) to fetch data while PS script is executing.

```
app.post('/ExecutePS', async function computeWSetImmediate(req, res) {  
  console.log('Fetching Users...');
  var ThisSelTNow = req.body.ThisT;
  console.log(ThisSelTNow);

  function setImmediatePromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setImmediate(() => resolve());
    });
  }

  ps.addCommand("./public/NodeJSFetch.PS1", [ {
    name: 'SelectedTenantNow', value: ThisSelT
  } ])  
  ps.invoke().then(output =>
    {      
      response.send({message:"All users were fetched"});
    });
  await setImmediatePromise(); 
});
```

When I click on "CallScript" button the script executes but Event Loop hangs and clicking on "GetData" does nothing.

If I execute below code I am able to get data by clicking on "GetData" button. In other words Event Loop is able to listen to events.

```
app.post('/ExecutePS', async function computeWSetImmediate(req, res) {  
  console.log('Fetching Users...');
  var ThisSelTNow = req.body.ThisT;
  console.log(ThisSelTNow);

  function setImmediatePromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setImmediate(() => resolve());
    });
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {    
    console.log(i);    
    await setImmediatePromise()
  }
});
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What proof do you have that the `/ExecutePS` route is blocking the event loop from doing anything else?  Just because you don't see a result in your client from pressing the GetData button is not proof at all that your problem is a blocking of the event loop on the server.

Comment: So as I stated in my question - clicking on second button "GetData" does nothing and browser hangs. I have been trying to fix it myself but to no avail. If you execute second example one with for loop you can see results in console and can also see Event Loop responding to "GetData" events.

Comment: Also, what do you think `await setImmediatePromise();` at the end of your function is actually doing?  It looks to me like it's doing nothing as there is no code after it in the function that would be affected the the `await` and nothing is using the promise returns from the `async` function.

Comment: Browser hangs is potentially very different than server event loop is stuck.  That's why I'm asking you how you KNOW it's the server event loop that is stuck because I see nothing in your first `/ExecutePS` route that blocks the event loop unless `ps.addCommand()` or `ps.invoke()` are doing that.  And, if they are, the `await setImmediatePromise()` won't help with that at all. So far, your assertions in your question aren't making any sense to me so my gut is telling me that you've made some wrong assumptions about where the problem is.  That's why I'm asking how you know what you assert.

Comment: That powershell script takes at least five minutes to finish. So how can I write execution of PS Script and still allow Event Loop to respond to other events while script is executing in background.

Comment: Your second `/ExecutePS` route doesn't have the ps stuff in it so that second code block does not really help with anything other than a route handler with nothing else in it that just calls `setImmediatePromise()` will not block the event loop.  But, your first code block has other stuff in it.  It appears to me like, if the event loop is actually getting blocked, then it's the `ps` methods doing it and that's where the fix needs to be.

Comment: Yes you are write its the PS method that is blocking but can't figure out how I make it work so Event Loop still continues to serve requests :(

Comment: Well, the PowerShell script needs to be run in a non-blocking child_process that is independent of other things you are trying to do.   Are you using the `node-powershell` module?  I'm trying to look at its code to see what its doing, but it's not simple to follow.  If it's blocking your event loop, you're not going to fix that with your `setImmediate()` experiments.  It will have to be fixed inside the powershell module or in how you configure it.

Comment: At first blush the node-powershell module appears to be using `child_process.spawn` which should be non-blocking.

Comment: Please add all code that is creating and configuring your `ps` object.  I need to see how you have it configured.

Comment: FYI, there are other reports of problems with node-powershell blocking the event loop.  Here's one report: https://github.com/rannn505/node-powershell/issues/81.

Comment: FYI, there's also another serious issue with node-powershell [here](https://github.com/rannn505/node-powershell/issues/94) that was reported in 2019 and is not yet fixed even though a fix has already been proposed.  It appears to me like this module is NOT being maintained in a timely manner.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help and investigation. I decided to run whole poweshell script in a job.